# How to pass control from one LUIS method to another?

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Is it possible to pass control from one LUIS method to another, or how to create a method that can be shared by several LUIS methods in the same way (something like a default reaction if the intent score is too low)?

Comment: Is there anything blocking you to call the second Luis method? Or do you want to recall Luis?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass control from one Luis Method to another:

```
  [LuisIntent("IntentOne")]
    public async Task IntentOneHandler(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await IntentTwoHandler(context, result);
    }

    [LuisIntent("IntentTwo")]
    public async Task IntentTwoHandler(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {         
        await context.PostAsync("IntentTwoResponse");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```

And the "None" intent should fire when no good intent match is found:

```
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task NoneHandler(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
    }
```